# What is the exact reason why some of these work and other's don't?

Tags: c++

Some of these just spit out 0's while others spit out correct random numbers. I think it has something to do with casting them to unsigned ints and throwing out the fractional parts but where exactly is the casting taking place?

`#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

const unsigned NUM_MIN {0};
const unsigned NUM_MAX {50};

int main ()
{
    // Seed random number generator.
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(nullptr)));

    size_t times {};
    do
    {
        // Get a random number between NUM_MIN and NUM_MAX.
        unsigned number {NUM_MIN + std::rand() / ((RAND_MAX + 1u) / NUM_MAX)};   // Works
        // unsigned number {NUM_MIN + std::rand() / (RAND_MAX / NUM_MAX)};          // Works.
        // unsigned number {NUM_MIN + (std::rand() / RAND_MAX) / NUM_MAX};             // Does not work.
        // unsigned number {NUM_MIN + std::rand() / RAND_MAX / NUM_MAX};            // Does not work.
        // unsigned number {NUM_MIN + (std::rand() / RAND_MAX) * NUM_MAX};          // Also does not work.
        // unsigned number {NUM_MIN + (std::rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1u)) * NUM_MAX};   // Doesn't work.

        std::cout << number << std::endl;
    } while (++times < 20);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}`

Comment: `std::rand() / RAND_MAX` will be zero due to integer-division for all instances unless `std::rand` actually returned `RAND_MAX`. The final test is just furthering that madness. Why you wouldn't use `std::uniform_int_distribution` and the proper facilities of `<random>` is the real pondering question here.

Comment: [Good discussion of why one should not use `rand`.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) Educational and funny. You don't get that often so enjoy it while you can.

Comment: None of them is correct. For the first two it's just harder to see. You should make yourself familiar with the modulus operation (`%` operator in C++).

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually "casting" that is the "problem" in all cases.

There is also the fact that integer division produces an integral result.  For positive operands, rounding is always toward zero.

And the fact that different operands have different precedence.  Multiplication and division have higher precedence than addition and subtraction  (and all have left-to-right associativity).   Brackets `()` are used to override.

> ```
> unsigned number {NUM_MIN + std::rand() / ((RAND_MAX + 1u) / NUM_MAX)};
> ```

converts `RAND_MAX` to `unsigned` (since it has being added to `1u`).  Then, since both operands are `unsigned`, `((RAND_MAX + 1u) / NUM_MAX)` produces a result of type `unsigned`.  The result of `std::rand()` is converted to `unsigned`.  All other operations in the expression have `unsigned` operands and produce `unsigned` results.

> ```
> unsigned number {NUM_MIN + std::rand() / (RAND_MAX / NUM_MAX)};
> ```

`RAND_MAX` is converted to `unsigned`, so `(RAND_MAX / NUM_MAX)` produces a result of type `unsigned`.   `std::rand()` is then converted to `unsigned` for the division, and all other operations in this expression have `unsigned` operands and `unsigned` results.

> ```
> unsigned number {NUM_MIN + (std::rand() / RAND_MAX) / NUM_MAX};   
> unsigned number {NUM_MIN + std::rand() / RAND_MAX / NUM_MAX};   
> unsigned number {NUM_MIN + (std::rand() / RAND_MAX) * NUM_MAX};
> ```

In all three of these cases, `std::rand()` and `RAND_MAX` both give positive values of type `int`, so `std::rand() / RAND_MAX` is computed as `int`.  This will be zero, since `RAND_MAX` is the upper bound for results returned by `rand()`.   That zero value is converted to `unsigned` for division (multiplication in the third case) by `NUM_MAX`, and all other operations are performed with `unsigned` operands and results.    The net effect is that `number` will be initialised as equal to `NUM_MIN`.

> ```
> unsigned number {NUM_MIN + (std::rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1u)) * NUM_MAX};
> ```

The logic here is identical to the previous, except that division is done using `unsigned`.

You might also want to revisit your definition of "works".   The two examples you have commented as "works" produce different results.